# How to make pdf in java?

Tags: java

How do I create pdf file of jsp page, exactly same as the jsp page?

itext.jar but not works for jsp pages, we can create manual pdf using itext.

```
<script>
function pdff(){     
var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
var top_left_margin = 15;
var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);
var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;
var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height/PDF_Height)-1;
Html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf[0],
allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas)     {
canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin,
top_left_margin,
canvas_image_width,
canvas_image_height);
for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG',
top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)
+(top_left_margin*4),
canvas_image_width,
canvas_image_height);
}
alert(-(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4));
pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
});
};     
</script>
```

Code is not working. Performing no actions. Nothing happens.

Comment: What does the code have to do with Java and iText?

Comment: i have to make pdf from jsp page, i got ample of solution related to itext.jar. itext.jar file is used to create pdf file using java servlet. But I want same pdf as that of jsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. You are using wrong js files, acc to me because this is the only when save pdf option is not working.

Download the correct version of Html2canvas.js and jspdf.js You can download working code form github (Url is given below)

https://github.com/s4satishverma/htmltopdf

Moreover, use below CDNS

// html2canvas.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js

// jspdf.js

https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js

https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js

Comment: Thanks satish, for the github code. It really helps alot.